# PHP undefined session

Tags: php

after user has logged in, it isn't displaying any content.

Here is my code for `login.php`:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"><br />
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
        require'core/connect.php';

        $query = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
        $query->execute(array(
            ':username' => $_POST['username'],
            ':password' => $_POST['password']
            ));

        $_SESSION['username'] = $query;

        if($query->rowCount() == 0)
        {
            echo 'username / password was incorrect.';
        } else{
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

Here's my index page where the content is suppose to be displayed after logging in, I don't see what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php
session_start();

require'core/connect.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo "welcome!";
} else {
    echo "Please log in first to see this page.";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don’t seem to be starting the session in the `login.php`. So when writing something to the session variables (`$_SESSION`) those will just immediately vanish. You will have to add `session_start()` to the beginning of your login file too (that is *at the very top*, before any output), to make this work.

Also, this check seems backwards:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo "welcome!";
}
```

I.e. if the session variable is *not* set, you are welcoming the user. You probably want to remove the `!` there.

Further note, that storing an executed query in a session variable will likely not work. You should fetch the username from the query result first, and then set the session variable:

```
$query->execute( ... );

if($query->rowCount() == 0) {
    echo 'username / password was incorrect.';
} else {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $query->fetchColumn(0); // or something like that
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put `session_start()` before you set any `$_SESSION` variables

Also, you're checking if the username is not set, as opposed to is set, so do it like this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo "welcome ".$_SESSION['username'];
}
```

Try sending the data via a `GET` headerto the `login.php`, and set the session variables from there.

Comment: so instead of $_SESSION['username'] = $query; I should put a $_POST['username'] = $query; ?

Comment: You'd send a header actually

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `$query` to `$_SESSION['username']` which does not look correct. `$query` is a resource after finishing the query not a string IMHO.

Try this:

```
else{
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
```